# How to merge and diff lists in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, collections

How do I perform an operation that checks the IDs and removes the different elements of the first list and adds the different elements of the second list?

The letters are a Entity Id. The numbers are a object reference in memory.

```
List 1: A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5
List 2: B:6, C:7, E:8, F:9

RemovedElements: A:1, D:4
InvalidElements: B:6, C:7, E:8
ResultList: B:2, C:3, E:5, F:9
```

Does anyone know if there is any function that performs this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val l1 = Seq(('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5))
l1: Seq[(Char, Int)] = List((A,1), (B,2), (C,3), (D,4), (E,5))

scala> val l2 = Seq(('B', 6), ('C', 7), ('E', 8), ('F', 9))
l2: Seq[(Char, Int)] = List((B,6), (C,7), (E,8), (F,9))

scala> l2 map { e =>
     |   l1.find(_._1 == e._1).getOrElse(e)
     | }
res51: Seq[(Char, Int)] = List((B,2), (C,3), (E,5), (F,9))
```